Decreasing RO for interior basement door
I am in the process of finishing my basement. I currently have a bi folding door that I want to make into a single door. The rough opening is currently 36-1/2” W x 80-1/2h.  I can take off one of the 2x4 along the head (making it 82” but would I cut a piece of treated 2x4 for the bottom plate, anchor it to the floor and just add a couple jack studs along that small bottom piece?

I am not understanding your question- Making the RO taller is good by removing the bottom 2x4 at the head. An 82" RO height should be fine unless the door will have a threshold in which case you will need more height. Are you trying to install a pre-hung 36" door ? The RO width would need to be 38" minimum.

A photo or sketch would sure help you here.  Are you looking to use a pre-hung door?  Why do you need a bottom plate?  Assume this is not a load bearing wall?

@Huesmann, the bottom plate should be treated lumber, as was indicated. I'd agree about skipping it if not for that.

@isherwood given that there are no pics of the framing (existing or proposed), I may have misunderstood the OP's intent.

I assume you'd like to arrive at a rough opening of 32¼" (appropriate for a 2-6 or 30" door). Given that, you need to reduce by 4¼". You can do that according to your suggestions. Some tips:

Cut the 2x4 on the bottom of the header at 35¼" from the unmodified side of the opening. Leave the stub in place as a backer for your new jack studs. It'll help hold position when you toenail them in.

Attach your new bottom plate with construction adhesive. It'll be somewhat fragile, being so short, and it'll be difficult to attach it to the concrete without cracking it. Pilot for any fasteners you do use.

Fit your new trimmers snugly. The compression force will help keep the plate in position.


